# Does multi-threading cause to utilize more CPU in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, cpu-usage

If I want to use most of my CPU power, can I separate my python code to parallel blocks and run each of them with a thread?

Comment: Yes, of course.  Each active thread running can use a separate core.

Comment: @selbie: I think you're confusing Python multi-threading and multi-processing…

Comment: @selbie: but it doesn't work for me and I didn't see any significant difference.

Comment: See [An introduction to parallel programming using Python's multiprocessing module](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html) particularly the [Multi-Threading vs. Multi-Processing](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html#multi-threading-vs-multi-processing) section.

Comment: Multi threading won't be as effective as you might assume, because the GIL will often keep more than one thread from executing at the same time.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Does it mean there is no difference between single thread and multi-threads programs regarding CPU-usage?

Comment: I wouldn't say there's *no* difference, just that it's less than the number of threads might expect you to believe. I'm not well versed on the details so I can't give you a sense of the difference.

Comment: @AliRasaii the difference is in the problem, if you have I/O bound problem then concurrency (multiple threads) will help because you're multiplexing I/O over time. If you have a CPU bound problem then you need parallelism

Comment: We'll never know how the OP's program can be improved with more threads and processes if they don't post their code and show a [mcve]

Comment: @selbie: My question is general about thread behavior in python, I don't want to apply it for a particular code.

Comment: You said, "but I don't see any significant difference".  I can't tell what you are seeing because you didn't post any code.

Comment: @selbie: I said that in response to your answer according to each thread use one core to processing.